# Are there migration plugins for D8 sources?

Tags: migrations

I found 2 references here for migrating D8 to D8, but both are very outdated.

Certainly there will be a need to do D7 -> D9 or D8 -> D9 migrations for many, but there are also current use cases. One is migrating from a multisite to individual sites.

Mine is the site restructuring its content types, and it would be far simpler to add custom code to a source plugin than to do all of it in custom code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is. Drupal core has a `content_entity` source plugin that's a part of the Migrate Drupal module.

The [one caveat](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2992746) with this plugin is it can only handle scenarios where the source/destination DB is the same, which sounds like your scenario here.

If source/destination DB isn't the same, the [Drupal 8 migration](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_drupal_d8) provides a `d8_entity` source plugin that does support this scenario.